# How To implement Single page application with angular 2

Tags: angular

Im a little bit confused, how angular 2 works internally in terms of single page application ? does it loads ressources (html,css...) by modules or by components ?
I want to know how can i create a single page application using angular 2.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sassi.  This site is really meant for more of helping with specific code problems, not discussing general ideas or giving tutorials.  Try going onto Google and search around for Angular 2 tutorials.  There are plenty of resources that can get you going there.  If you run into any problems while working with the framework, you can always come back and post on here and we'd be happy to help :-)  In the mean time, here's a tutorial that might help you get started https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-implement-a-single-page-application-with-angular2/index.html

Answer (score -1):

You can create a out-of-box new application using Angular Cli.  Look up their documentation.

Comment: Please do not encourage bad questions with one-line answers.